# mean squared error greater zero even though input equals output and weights initialized by one

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I try to train a network where input = output, or more mathematical: f(x) = x <==> y = x <==> x = x

Therefore I have a input of size; [1, 500, 500, 3] and my network looks like this:

```
logits = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=x, filters=3, kernel_size=1, padding='SAME', name ='logits', kernel_initializer=tf.ones_initializer(), trainable=True)
```

Then I calculate the loss:

```
loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(x, logits) > 0
```

but the network does not show the loss of 0.

In my opinion I thought if I set x = y the loss should be 0 when initializing the weights with ones.

Is there something wrong in my mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`conv2d`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d) operation sums over the channels of your input. Thus, initialising the kernel with ones will give you identical output channels, each of which is the sum over your input channels.

Note that unless you set the `bias_initializer` to zero or set the `use_bias` parameter to `False`, the randomly-initialised bias will also affect your output.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


with tf.Graph().as_default():
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 500, 500, 3])
    y = tf.layers.conv2d(x, 3, 1, padding='same', use_bias=False, kernel_initializer=tf.ones_initializer())
    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

# Evaluate
np.random.seed(1)
_x = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (1, 500, 500, 3))
_y = sess.run(y, {x: _x})

# Check that the channels are identical
np.testing.assert_allclose(_y[..., 0], _y[..., 1])

# Check that each channel is the sum over channels
np.testing.assert_allclose(_y[..., 0], _x.sum(axis=-1), rtol=1e-5)
```

Comment: What do you mean sums over the channels of your input? do you mean if I had channels = 1 there wouldn`t be a sum?
Note: I set use_bias=False in another test and I still did not work

Comment: I think the linked documentation for `conv2d` explains it better than I could.

Comment: Yeah so as I said, if channels = 1 there is no sum, hence it should work as in the loss should return 0.0.

Comment: Yes, if the inputs have exactly one channel, each of the output channels will be identical to the input.

Comment: Okay, I will reduce my input channels to one and then we will see if the network "learns" the easiest task there will ever be in one iteration.

Comment: Okay, that works. So initializing all the weights with 1/3 for 3 channels should do the trick as well. What I do not understand why the summation is done in the first place. Do you know what is behind this idea?

Comment: No, I'm afraid initialising with 1/3 will average the input channels rather than providing the identity. If you truly want to compute the identity using a convolutional operation, have a look at the [Levi Civita symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol). 

The idea behind summing over the inputs is to combine information: For example, you may have identified a round object in an RGB image. Apples and oranges are easily distinguished by combining information from the different colour channels.

Comment: Correction: The link above should have been to [generalisations of the Kronecker Delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta#Generalizations) rather than the Levi Civita symbol.

Comment: I thought about the whole averaging thing and I understood it now! Sorry for the inconvenience. It clearly makes sense to average over the channels. However, there is an option where it is not averaged over channels: `tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d`